# Watch Position Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular6

Hi guys I need help in how to watch position in google maps with Ionic 3, I would like that upload position in real time in the firebase 
In my home.ts I have the following code :

```
    getMyPosition() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((result) => {
      this.positionTruck = new google.maps.LatLng(result.coords.latitude, result.coords.longitude);
      const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: this.positionTruck,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      }    
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      this.truckMarker(this.positionTruck);

      let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
      watch.subscribe((data) => {
      let truck = { latitude: data.coords.latitude, longitude: data.coords.longitude };
        this.truckService.updateGeolocation(this.truck.key, truck);
        console.log(data.coords)
      });

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Erro ao tentar pegar sua localização ', error);
    })
  }
```

And now I have this code in service to update truck.service:

```
    update(key: string, truck: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.list(this.PATH)
            .update(key, (truck))
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch((e) => reject())
    })
  }
```

this way when I test on the device, the home page giving refresh in page, why ?
Is this form correctly the update position ? help please.

Answer (score 1):

import : `import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';`

and declare :

```
public lat: number = 0;
public lng: number = 0;
```

and add in your code

```
let options = {
      frequency: 3000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    };

this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {

  console.log(position.coords.latitude + '   ++++++++++ ' + position.coords.longitude);

  // Run update inside of Angular's zone
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    );

  });

});
```

Comment: right, but I have some questions, 1 - I'm calling the getMyPosition () method inside ionViewDidLoad () {
     this.getMyPosition ();
   }
getMyPosition () {
     this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (). then ((result) => {
....
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition ();
       watch.subscribe ((data) => {
Should I place watchposition here?

Comment: 2 - need to call update method in service like i did
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition ();
       watch.subscribe ((data) => {
         let truck = {latitude: data.coords.latitude, longitude: data.coords.longitude};
         this.truckService.updateGeolocation (this.truck.key, truck);
as above?

Comment: where I call this method wacth ionviewDidLoad, Constructor , inside my method getMyPosition ?